# problem in adding anchor to the list dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, dom

am creating an unordered list using javascript dynamically from an JSON object.

```
function renderList(branches) {  
    var ul = document.createElement("ul");
    for (var i=0, n=branches.length; i<n; i++) {
        var branch = branches[i];
        var li = document.createElement("li");
                var text = document.createTextNode(branch.name);
                li.appendChild(text);
        if (branch.branches) {
           li.appendChild(renderList(branch.branches));
        }
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }      
    return ul; 
}

function renderTree()
    {
    var treeRoot = document.getElementById("tree");
    var treeObj = {"root":
            [{
                   "name": "File",
                   "branches":[
                 {"name": "New"},
                             {"name": "Save"},
                             {"name": "Exit"}
                               ]  
                }]
          };
    treeRoot.appendChild(renderList(treeObj.root));
}
```

what are the changes required in json & javascript to add anchor to the list dynamically?

dynamically from  `<li> File </li>` to `<li> <a href="yahoo.com"> File </a> <li>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the `text` in the line `li.appendChild(text);` with an anchor node:

```
function renderList(branches) {  
    var ul = document.createElement("ul");
    for (var i=0, n=branches.length; i<n; i++) {
        var branch = branches[i];
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        var text = document.createTextNode(branch.name);

        // new code here
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.setAttribute('href', 'http://yahoo.com')
        a.appendChild( text );
        //

        li.appendChild( a );
        ...
```

Where are your urls stored? (You can update the code above to replace the hard coded url with your actual value if you have it stored somewhere.)